# Why do I have two session id in my header?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, session-cookies

I'm using PHP5.3, Apache 2.2 and Zend Framework 1.11 and when I do a request with curl, I got two Set-Cookie headers with two differents session id.

Any  ideas?

```
> POST /api/register HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic Ymd1ZXJ0eQ==
> Host: api.domain.tld
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 66
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 13:27:07 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
< Set-Cookie: SESSID=vtvackh55bj1up3ouoq4bhk545; expires=Thu, 06-Dec-2012 19:15:53 GMT; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: SESSID=79a1g98e0pkqlq8fo7elpe9492; expires=Thu, 06-Dec-2012 19:15:53 GMT; path=/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Content-Length: 128
< Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at that acceptance rating

Comment: Note that I've no problem to accept an answer until I've a good one enough... Accepted answer are not only a score to increase ;)

Comment: There's no way anyone can answer this question without seeing your PHP code as it relates to the cURL query.

Comment: Note that this behavior is also reproducing within a browser

Comment: @Trent This is not necessarily a *problem*, because the latter value will override the first. As long as your session is maintained correctly, I would not worry about it. However, although I have never seen it, I would guess this *could* be caused by calling `session_start()` more than once, or by overriding the session ID. Really, we would need to see the code to even guess at *where* the problem is, though.

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934854/serverhttp-cookie-returns-two-phpsessid?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Your server application is emitting the `Set-Cookie` header twice. This can come from anywhere, impossible to tell without seeing all the code.

Look for things that deal with session handling. If there is third party code involved, disable it and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

From [Zend 1.11 documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.auth.introduction.html):

> By default, Zend_Auth provides persistent storage of the identity from a successful authentication attempt using the PHP session.

Maybe you used somewhere AuthAdapter which start session and later on you are trying to manipulate it on your own starting another session with different session id.

I've experienced this issue in Zend 2. 
I first used AuthenticationService to authenticate and after successful authentication I tried to use [Zend Session Container](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.session.container.html) to manipulate session.
I've used session container to explicitly regenerateId() and set some additional headers like secure, http_only and as a result I had two session headers like you.