# $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] return's two PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am getting two `PHPSESSID` while printing `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`. Actually I don't know how it is set twice, its only in my local system.
When I check the SERVER cookie it like:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'];

//result 

'fe_toolbar=false; 
fe_toolbar=false; 
PHPSESSID=4tvbovcjk0msf9dvibeb31c2b7; 
langId=1; 
backendLangId=2; 
PHPSESSID=46aagg1hg7as2uh9bihjlpp8h7'
```

When I check my cookie alone like :

```
print_r($_COOKIE);    

//result 

array (
       'fe_toolbar' => 'false',
       'PHPSESSID' => '4tvbovcjk0msf9dvibeb31c2b7',
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple cookies with the same name. This happens when you set  cookie with different Path or Domain attributes. They are **all** send to the server.

[image]

The [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) specific

> if the Cookie header contains two cookies with the same name (e.g.,
> that were set with different Path or Domain attributes), servers SHOULD NOT rely upon the order in which these cookies appear in the header.

Your `$_COOKIE` will be populated with one of these values.